# Complex query on SQL database to get winner of election

Tags: mysql

I have a few tables that are set up like so:

Table `past_elections`:

```
election_ID bigint(15) unsigned;
Date date;
Race varchar(32)
```

Table `candidates`:

```
Candidate_ID bigint(15) unsigned;
FirstName varchar(60);
LastName varchar(60)
```

Table `past_elections-candidates`:

```
PastElection bigint(15); 
Candidate bigint(15); 
Votes int(8) unsigned
```

The `past_elections-candidates` is an intermediate table which links the Primary keys for the Candidate_ID in the candidates table with the election_ID in the past_elections table and I set it up this way because technically a candidate can be in the candidate table and run for more than one race on the same election (Think partial term limits or special elections where they also want to retain their seat for the following term) or where they run for reelection in another year. That is why I made that one-to-many relationship.

My question is, how do I make a query on the database to find all the winners of their races? What about a query to find out which people won their elections with less than X percentage of total votes? I know I'll probably have to use an aggregate function like `MAX()` along with an `INNER JOIN` and a `GROUP BY` but this one seems complex. I'm hoping someone has done something the same or similar before. Although I'm probably going to be told I set up my tables in the most inefficient manner possible for such a query. (Crossing my fingers.)

Comment: So I've found out how to find the winner as long as I know the Primary Key of the election_ID: ``SELECT FirstName, LastName, Votes / (SELECT SUM(Votes) FROM `past_elections-candidates` pec WHERE pec.PastElection = 253) percent_votes
FROM `past_elections-candidates` pec 
INNER JOIN `candidates` c ON pec.Candidate = c.Candidate_ID
WHERE pec.PastElection = 253
ORDER BY percent_votes DESC
LIMIT 1``

But I'd like to modify this where it gives me a list of all winners without having to specify a primary key. Basically, do this for all distinct primary keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the winner for any event, you need to find the maximum votes per election and then join that back to the `past_elections-candidates` table to find the candidate number, then join to the candidates table to get their details:

```
SELECT pe.election_ID as elec,
       c.FirstName,
       c.LastName,
       pecs.max_votes AS votes,
       pecs.max_votes / pecs.total_votes AS percent
FROM past_elections pe
JOIN `past_elections-candidates` pec ON pec.PastElection = pe.election_ID
JOIN (SELECT PastElection, 
             MAX(Votes) AS max_votes,
             SUM(Votes) AS total_votes
      FROM `past_elections-candidates`
      GROUP BY PastElection) pecs ON pecs.PastElection = pec.PastElection AND pecs.max_votes = pec.votes
JOIN candidates c ON c.Candidate_ID = pec.Candidate
```

Output:

```
elec    FirstName   LastName    votes   percent
1       Aladdin     Arabia      200     0.5714
2       Robin       Hood        150     0.4286
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qwvEUiNfF11n2ZK7iS9CRp/1)

Comment: Fabulous. You make it sound so easy but I've been driving myself crazy overthinking this problem. You used less derived tables too which should make it faster.

Comment: any idea how to get the first 2, 3, etc. {seats} maximum voter earners in this case? For example, if the state_senator election record had seats = 2 then I'd expect the return of Aladdin for elec 1, Robin Hood and King Kong for elec 2.

Comment: @boymeetscode that's a significantly more complex problem and worthy of another question.